# Wpf webbrowser wont load sharepoint module

Tags: wpf, sharepoint, webbrowser-control

We are currently trying to create a simple WPF webbrowser, that opens on a sharepoint site. On this site there are some learning modules, if you start one of these you get redirected to a elearningforce module, the problem is that whenever i try to start one of the modules from the wpf webbrowser, it is just stuck at "loading learning module". I have never worked with either wpf webbrowser or elearningforce before, do i need to allow the redirect or something?

Comment: do you have an internet problem? i tried running the video at https://www.elearningforce.com/lms365-videos on a wpf webbrowser and it runs fine.

Comment: I can run the video just fine, if i set the video as the webbrowser source. The problem is when it has to redirect from sharepoint first

Comment: Could you please show us some code.

Comment: I have zero code, it is just a new wpf project, with a webbrowser dragged from the toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) instead, which enables me to change the browser the wpf application uses from IE to Chrome, which solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The WPF `WebBrowser` control uses the Internet Explorer ActiveX control embedded within its window. So, it has the same limitations as the installed version of Internet Explorer.  By default, it will be using IE 7 compatibility so more modern `JavaScript` may not work quite right.

You can force the control to use a more modern rendering engine by setting a registry key as described in this Microsoft article: [Browser Emulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)

You will need to add an entry for your .exe name. For example, if your application is myapp.exe, it would be something like this to get IE 11 rendering.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     myapp.exe = (DWORD) 00011000
```